# Hydration failed error in Next.js with React when transitioning from AuthForm to Home component

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am encountering an error message "Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server" in a Next.js application with React. I am having trouble understanding the cause of this error and how to resolve it.

In my code, I have a function called isLoggedIn() that determines whether a user is logged in or not. When isLoggedIn() returns true, the application should transition from the AuthForm component to the Home component without any errors.

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { useQuery } from 'react-query';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';
import { GetServerSideProps } from 'next';
import { useTranslation } from 'next-i18next';
import { serverSideTranslations } from 'next-i18next/serverSideTranslations';
import Head from 'next/head';

import { useCreateReducer } from '@/hooks/useCreateReducer';

import useErrorService from '@/services/errorService';
import useApiService from '@/services/useApiService';

import {
  cleanConversationHistory,
  cleanSelectedConversation,
} from '@/utils/app/clean';
import { DEFAULT_SYSTEM_PROMPT, DEFAULT_TEMPERATURE } from '@/utils/app/const';
import {
  saveConversation,
  saveConversations,
  updateConversation,
} from '@/utils/app/conversation';
import { saveFolders } from '@/utils/app/folders';
import { savePrompts } from '@/utils/app/prompts';
import { getSettings } from '@/utils/app/settings';

import { Conversation } from '@/types/chat';
import { KeyValuePair } from '@/types/data';
import { FolderInterface, FolderType } from '@/types/folder';
import { OpenAIModelID, OpenAIModels, fallbackModelID } from '@/types/openai';
import { Prompt } from '@/types/prompt';

import { Chat } from '@/components/Chat/Chat';
import { Chatbar } from '@/components/Chatbar/Chatbar';
import { Navbar } from '@/components/Mobile/Navbar';
import Promptbar from '@/components/Promptbar';

import HomeContext from './home.context';
import { HomeInitialState, initialState } from './home.state';

import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

interface Props {
  serverSideApiKeyIsSet: boolean;
  serverSidePluginKeysSet: boolean;
  defaultModelId: OpenAIModelID;
}

const Home = ({
  serverSideApiKeyIsSet,
  serverSidePluginKeysSet,
  defaultModelId,
}: Props) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation('chat');
  const { getModels } = useApiService();
  const { getModelsError } = useErrorService();
  const [initialRender, setInitialRender] = useState<boolean>(true);

  const contextValue = useCreateReducer<HomeInitialState>({
    initialState,
  });

  const {
    state: {
      apiKey,
      lightMode,
      folders,
      conversations,
      selectedConversation,
      prompts,
      temperature,
    },
    dispatch,
  } = contextValue;

  const stopConversationRef = useRef<boolean>(false);

  const { data, error, refetch } = useQuery(
    ['GetModels', apiKey, serverSideApiKeyIsSet],
    ({ signal }) => {
      if (!apiKey && !serverSideApiKeyIsSet) return null;

      return getModels(
        {
          key: apiKey,
        },
        signal,
      );
    },
    { enabled: true, refetchOnMount: false },
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data) dispatch({ field: 'models', value: data });
  }, [data, dispatch]);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({ field: 'modelError', value: getModelsError(error) });
  }, [dispatch, error, getModelsError]);

  // FETCH MODELS ----------------------------------------------

  const handleSelectConversation = (conversation: Conversation) => {
    dispatch({
      field: 'selectedConversation',
      value: conversation,
    });

    saveConversation(conversation);
  };

  // FOLDER OPERATIONS  --------------------------------------------

  const handleCreateFolder = (name: string, type: FolderType) => {
    const newFolder: FolderInterface = {
      id: uuidv4(),
      name,
      type,
    };

    const updatedFolders = [...folders, newFolder];

    dispatch({ field: 'folders', value: updatedFolders });
    saveFolders(updatedFolders);
  };

  const handleDeleteFolder = (folderId: string) => {
    const updatedFolders = folders.filter((f) => f.id !== folderId);
    dispatch({ field: 'folders', value: updatedFolders });
    saveFolders(updatedFolders);

    const updatedConversations: Conversation[] = conversations.map((c) => {
      if (c.folderId === folderId) {
        return {
          ...c,
          folderId: null,
        };
      }

      return c;
    });

    dispatch({ field: 'conversations', value: updatedConversations });
    saveConversations(updatedConversations);

    const updatedPrompts: Prompt[] = prompts.map((p) => {
      if (p.folderId === folderId) {
        return {
          ...p,
          folderId: null,
        };
      }

      return p;
    });

    dispatch({ field: 'prompts', value: updatedPrompts });
    savePrompts(updatedPrompts);
  };

  const handleUpdateFolder = (folderId: string, name: string) => {
    const updatedFolders = folders.map((f) => {
      if (f.id === folderId) {
        return {
          ...f,
          name,
        };
      }

      return f;
    });

    dispatch({ field: 'folders', value: updatedFolders });

    saveFolders(updatedFolders);
  };

  // CONVERSATION OPERATIONS  --------------------------------------------

  const handleNewConversation = () => {
    const lastConversation = conversations[conversations.length - 1];

    const newConversation: Conversation = {
      id: uuidv4(),
      name: t('New Conversation'),
      messages: [],
      model: lastConversation?.model || {
        id: OpenAIModels[defaultModelId].id,
        name: OpenAIModels[defaultModelId].name,
        maxLength: OpenAIModels[defaultModelId].maxLength,
        tokenLimit: OpenAIModels[defaultModelId].tokenLimit,
      },
      prompt: DEFAULT_SYSTEM_PROMPT,
      temperature: lastConversation?.temperature ?? DEFAULT_TEMPERATURE,
      folderId: null,
    };

    const updatedConversations = [...conversations, newConversation];

    dispatch({ field: 'selectedConversation', value: newConversation });
    dispatch({ field: 'conversations', value: updatedConversations });

    saveConversation(newConversation);
    saveConversations(updatedConversations);

    dispatch({ field: 'loading', value: false });
  };

  const handleUpdateConversation = (
    conversation: Conversation,
    data: KeyValuePair,
  ) => {
    const updatedConversation = {
      ...conversation,
      [data.key]: data.value,
    };

    const { single, all } = updateConversation(
      updatedConversation,
      conversations,
    );

    dispatch({ field: 'selectedConversation', value: single });
    dispatch({ field: 'conversations', value: all });
  };

  // EFFECTS  --------------------------------------------

  useEffect(() => {
    if (window.innerWidth < 640) {
      dispatch({ field: 'showChatbar', value: false });
    }
  }, [selectedConversation]);

  useEffect(() => {
    defaultModelId &&
      dispatch({ field: 'defaultModelId', value: defaultModelId });
    serverSideApiKeyIsSet &&
      dispatch({
        field: 'serverSideApiKeyIsSet',
        value: serverSideApiKeyIsSet,
      });
    serverSidePluginKeysSet &&
      dispatch({
        field: 'serverSidePluginKeysSet',
        value: serverSidePluginKeysSet,
      });
  }, [defaultModelId, serverSideApiKeyIsSet, serverSidePluginKeysSet]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const settings = getSettings();
    if (settings.theme) {
      dispatch({
        field: 'lightMode',
        value: settings.theme,
      });
    }

    const apiKey = localStorage.getItem('apiKey');

    if (serverSideApiKeyIsSet) {
      dispatch({ field: 'apiKey', value: '' });

      localStorage.removeItem('apiKey');
    } else if (apiKey) {
      dispatch({ field: 'apiKey', value: apiKey });
    }

    const pluginKeys = localStorage.getItem('pluginKeys');
    if (serverSidePluginKeysSet) {
      dispatch({ field: 'pluginKeys', value: [] });
      localStorage.removeItem('pluginKeys');
    } else if (pluginKeys) {
      dispatch({ field: 'pluginKeys', value: pluginKeys });
    }

    if (window.innerWidth < 640) {
      dispatch({ field: 'showChatbar', value: false });
      dispatch({ field: 'showPromptbar', value: false });
    }

    const showChatbar = localStorage.getItem('showChatbar');
    if (showChatbar) {
      dispatch({ field: 'showChatbar', value: showChatbar === 'true' });
    }

    const showPromptbar = localStorage.getItem('showPromptbar');
    if (showPromptbar) {
      dispatch({ field: 'showPromptbar', value: showPromptbar === 'true' });
    }

    const folders = localStorage.getItem('folders');
    if (folders) {
      dispatch({ field: 'folders', value: JSON.parse(folders) });
    }

    const prompts = localStorage.getItem('prompts');
    if (prompts) {
      dispatch({ field: 'prompts', value: JSON.parse(prompts) });
    }

    const conversationHistory = localStorage.getItem('conversationHistory');
    if (conversationHistory) {
      const parsedConversationHistory: Conversation[] =
        JSON.parse(conversationHistory);
      const cleanedConversationHistory = cleanConversationHistory(
        parsedConversationHistory,
      );

      dispatch({ field: 'conversations', value: cleanedConversationHistory });
    }

    const selectedConversation = localStorage.getItem('selectedConversation');
    if (selectedConversation) {
      const parsedSelectedConversation: Conversation =
        JSON.parse(selectedConversation);
      const cleanedSelectedConversation = cleanSelectedConversation(
        parsedSelectedConversation,
      );

      dispatch({
        field: 'selectedConversation',
        value: cleanedSelectedConversation,
      });
    } else {
      const lastConversation = conversations[conversations.length - 1];
      dispatch({
        field: 'selectedConversation',
        value: {
          id: uuidv4(),
          name: t('New Conversation'),
          messages: [],
          model: OpenAIModels[defaultModelId],
          prompt: DEFAULT_SYSTEM_PROMPT,
          temperature: lastConversation?.temperature ?? DEFAULT_TEMPERATURE,
          folderId: null,
        },
      });
    }
  }, [
    defaultModelId,
    dispatch,
    serverSideApiKeyIsSet,
    serverSidePluginKeysSet,
  ]);

  return (
    <HomeContext.Provider
      value={{
        ...contextValue,
        handleNewConversation,
        handleCreateFolder,
        handleDeleteFolder,
        handleUpdateFolder,
        handleSelectConversation,
        handleUpdateConversation,
      }}
    >
      <Head>
        <title>GigaSoft</title>
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta
          name="viewport"
          content="height=device-height ,width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no"
        />
        <link rel="icon" href="https://gigasoft.com.pl/logo.png" />
      </Head>
      {selectedConversation && (
        <main
          className={`flex h-screen w-screen flex-col text-sm text-white dark:text-white ${lightMode}`}
        >
          <div className="fixed top-0 w-full sm:hidden">
            <Navbar
              selectedConversation={selectedConversation}
              onNewConversation={handleNewConversation}
            />
          </div>

          <div className="flex h-full w-full pt-[48px] sm:pt-0">
            <Chatbar />

            <div className="flex flex-1">
              <Chat stopConversationRef={stopConversationRef} />
            </div>

            <Promptbar />
          </div>
        </main>
      )}
    </HomeContext.Provider>
  );
};

const endpoint = "https://main.gigasoft.com.pl/api.php";
import axios from 'axios';
let Status: Number = 0;
export const AuthForm = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [firstname, setFirstname] = useState('');
  const [surname, setSurname] = useState('');
  const [hwid, setHwid] = useState('');
  const [oldPassword, setOldPassword] = useState('');
  const [newPassword, setNewPassword] = useState('');
  const [oldEmail, setOldEmail] = useState('');
  const [newEmail, setNewEmail] = useState('');
  const [activeForm, setActiveForm] = useState('login');

  const register = () => {
    axios
      .get('/your-api-endpoint', {
        params: {
          action: 'register',
          firstname: firstname,
          surname: surname,
          email: email,
          password: password,
          hwid: hwid,
        },
      })
      .then((response) => console.log(response))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));
  };
  const login = () => {
    console.log("Clicked login");
    axios
      .get(endpoint, {
        params: {
          action: 'login',
          email: email,
          password: password,
        },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        const data = response.data.split('\n').reduce((acc: { [x: string]: any; }, line: { split: (arg0: string) => [any, any]; }) => {
          const [key, value] = line.split('=');
          if (key && value) {
            acc[key] = value;
          }
          return acc;
        }, {} as { [key: string]: string });
        console.log(data);
        if (data['Login'] === 's') {
          window.location.reload();
          Cookies.set('loggedIn', 'true');
          console.log('Zalogowano pomyślnie', data);

          Status = 1;
        } else {
          console.log('Nie udało się zalogować');
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));
  };

  const remindPassword = () => {
    axios
      .get('/your-api-endpoint', {
        params: {
          action: 'remind_password',
          email: email,
        },
      })
      .then((response) => console.log(response))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));
  };

  const changeEmail = () => {
    axios
      .get('/your-api-endpoint', {
        params: {
          action: 'change_email',
          old_email: oldEmail,
          new_email: newEmail,
          password: password,
        },
      })
      .then((response) => console.log(response))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));
  };

  const changePassword = () => {
    axios
      .get('/your-api-endpoint', {
        params: {
          action: 'changepass',
          email: email,
          oldpassword: oldPassword,
          newpassword: newPassword,
        },
      })
      .then((response) => console.log(response))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));
  };

  const handleFormChange = (formName: string) => {
    setActiveForm(formName);
  };
  const renderLoginForm = () => (
    <div className="login-form" style={darkFormStyle}>
      <img src="https://main.gigasoft.com.pl/logo.png" alt="Logo" style={logoStyle} /><br />
      <input type="email" placeholder="Email" onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} style={darkInputStyle} /><br />
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)} style={darkInputStyle} /><br />
      <button onClick={login} style={darkButtonStyle}>Log in</button>
      <div>
        <a href="#" onClick={() => setActiveForm('register')}>Register</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
        <a href="#" onClick={() => setActiveForm('remind_password')}>Forgot Password?</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  );

  const renderRegisterForm = () => (
    <div className="register-form" style={darkFormStyle}>
      <img src="https://main.gigasoft.com.pl/logo.png" alt="Logo" style={logoStyle} /><br />
      <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" onChange={(e) => setFirstname(e.target.value)} style={darkInputStyle} /><br />
      <input type="text" placeholder="Surname" onChange={(e) => setSurname(e.target.value)} style={darkInputStyle} /><br />
      <input type="email" placeholder="Email" onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} style={darkInputStyle} /><br />
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)} style={darkInputStyle} /><br />
      <button onClick={register} style={darkButtonStyle}>Register</button>
      <div>
        <a href="#" onClick={() => setActiveForm('login')}>Log in</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
        <a href="#" onClick={() => setActiveForm('remind_password')}>Forgot Password?</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  );

  const renderRemindPasswordForm = () => (
    <div className="remind-password-form" style={darkFormStyle}>
      <img src="https://main.gigasoft.com.pl/logo.png" alt="Logo" style={logoStyle} /><br />
      <input type="email" placeholder="Email" onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} style={darkInputStyle} /><br />
      <button onClick={remindPassword} style={darkButtonStyle}>Reset Password</button>
      <div>
        <a href="#" onClick={() => setActiveForm('login')}>Log in</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
        <a href="#" onClick={() => setActiveForm('register')}>Register</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  );

  const renderChangeEmailForm = () => (
    <div className="change-email-form" style={darkFormStyle}>
      <img src="https://main.gigasoft.com.pl/logo.png" alt="Logo" style={logoStyle} /><br />
      <input type="email" placeholder="Old Email" onChange={(e) => setOldEmail(e.target.value)} style={darkInputStyle} /><br />
      <input type="email" placeholder="New Email" onChange={(e) => setNewEmail(e.target.value)} style={darkInputStyle} /><br />
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)} style={darkInputStyle} /><br />
      <button onClick={changeEmail} style={darkButtonStyle}>Change Email</button>
      <div>
        <a href="#" onClick={() => setActiveForm('login')}>Log in</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
        <a href="#" onClick={() => setActiveForm('register')}>Register</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
        <a href="#" onClick={() => setActiveForm('remind_password')}>Forgot Password?</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  );

  const renderChangePasswordForm = () => (
    <div className="change-password-form" style={darkFormStyle}>
      <img src="https://main.gigasoft.com.pl/logo.png" alt="Logo" style={logoStyle} /><br />
      <input type="email" placeholder="Email" onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} style={darkInputStyle} /><br />
      <input type="password" placeholder="Old Password" onChange={(e) => setOldPassword(e.target.value)} style={darkInputStyle} /><br />
      <input type="password" placeholder="New Password" onChange={(e) => setNewPassword(e.target.value)} style={darkInputStyle} /><br />
      <button onClick={changePassword} style={darkButtonStyle}>Change Password</button>
      <div>
        <a href="#" onClick={() => setActiveForm('login')}>Log in</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
        <a href="#" onClick={() => setActiveForm('register')}>Register</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
        <a href="#" onClick={() => setActiveForm('remind_password')}>Forgot Password?</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  );

  const darkFormStyle = {
    backgroundColor: '#222',
    borderRadius: '16px',
    padding: '30px',
    boxShadow: '0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)',
    width: '100%',
  };
  const darkInputStyle = {
    backgroundColor: '#333',
    color: '#fff',
    borderRadius: '50px',
    padding: '10px',
    marginBottom: '20px',
    border: 'none',
    width: '100%',
  };
  const logoStyle = {
    maxWidth: '100px',
    margin: '0 auto',
  };
  const darkButtonStyle = {
    backgroundColor: '#777',
    color: '#fff',
    borderRadius: '50px',
    padding: '10px 20px',
    border: 'none',
    cursor: 'pointer',
    margin: '10px',
    width: '50%',
  };
  const backgroundStyle = {
    backgroundColor: '#111',
    height: '100vh',
    width: '100vw',
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  };


  const renderActiveForm = () => {
    switch (activeForm) {
      case 'login':
        return renderLoginForm();
      case 'register':
        return renderRegisterForm();
      case 'remind_password':
        return renderRemindPasswordForm();
      case 'change_email':
        return renderChangeEmailForm();
      case 'change_password':
        return renderChangePasswordForm();
      default:
        return null;
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="auth-form" style={backgroundStyle}>
      <div className="auth-forms" style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
        {renderActiveForm()}
        <div className="form-buttons">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

function isLoggedIn() {
  return Cookies.get('loggedIn') === 'true';
}

let component:any;
if (isLoggedIn()) {
  component = Home;
}
component = AuthForm;


export default component;

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async ({ locale }) => {
  const defaultModelId =
    (process.env.DEFAULT_MODEL ||
      Object.values(OpenAIModelID).includes(
        process.env.DEFAULT_MODEL as OpenAIModelID,
      ) ||
      process.env.DEFAULT_MODEL) ||
    fallbackModelID;

  let serverSidePluginKeysSet = false;

  const googleApiKey = process.env.GOOGLE_API_KEY;
  const googleCSEId = process.env.GOOGLE_CSE_ID;

  if (googleApiKey && googleCSEId) {
    serverSidePluginKeysSet = true;
  }

  return {
    props: {
      serverSideApiKeyIsSet: !!process.env.GS_API_KEY,
      defaultModelId,
      serverSidePluginKeysSet,
      ...(await serverSideTranslations(locale ?? 'pl', [
        'common',
        'chat',
        'sidebar',
        'markdown',
        'promptbar',
        'settings',
      ])),
    },
  };
};
```

I have tried everything from the documentation. However, I'm not familiar with TypeScript, and the code you see is from GitHub. But still, nothing is working :(